# Student loan payments and tax breaks

Tags: taxes, income-tax, student-loan

Forgive me for such a naïve question, but simply put: do student loan payments count as a deduction to gross income? I.e. if I make $50,000 per year gross and manage to pay $20,000 of loan debt in one year, will I only be tax liable for $30,000 of income? Or does this only apply to loan *interest payments*?

From [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/36991/30839) it seems that only $2,500 maximum of *interest* is deductible, and payments beyond that are not, but I'm really not sure, thus the question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's only the interest that is deductible. The principle payments don't offset income because when you received the loan it wasn't treated as income.

Comment: Also there are income limits to interest deductions.